# React: how to update an array in a usestate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using axios to populate an array with useState.

When the page render in the first time, the array update.
But when I call the function after an edit, nothing happens.

```
const [recursos, setRecursos] = useState([]);

const getRecursos = () => {
    Conexoes.Consultar(ma, password, "recurso").then(retorno => {
        console.log(retorno.Valores);
        setRecursos(retorno.Valores);
    })
        .catch(erro => {
            console.log(erro);
            alert("Erro Catch")
        }
        )
}
```

the function `Conexoes.Consultar` is a promise:

```
export const Consultar = (ma, password, tabela) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const chamada = {
            ma: ma,
            s: password,
            Banco: vars.dbase,
            Tabela: tabela,
            Filtros:
            {
                id: "%%"
            }
        };
        axios.post(vars.servidor + 'consultar/',
        chamada
        ).then((response) => {
            resolve(response.data);
        }, (erro) => {
            reject(error);
        });
    })
}
```

a function that is called after edition: (the `getRecursos()` is called, but nothing happens with the list )

```
const salvarEdicao = () => {
    if (titleEditar == "Editar Recurso") {
        Conexoes.Atualizar(ma, password, "recurso", { id: idEditar }, { nome: valorEditar, ativo: ativo }).then(retorno => {
            getRecursos();
            setMenuEditar(false);
        }).catch(erro => {
            console.log(erro);
            alert("Erro Catch")
        });
    }
}
```

the function `Atualizar` is a promise:

```
export const Atualizar = (ma, password, tabela, Filtros, Valores) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const command = JSON.stringify({
            ma: ma,
            s: password,
            Banco: vars.dbase,
            Tabela: tabela,
            Filtros: Filtros,
            Valores: Valores
        });
        console.log(command);
        axios.post(vars.servidor + 'atualizar/',
            command, { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }
        ).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            resolve(response.data);
        }, (erro) => {
            reject(erro);
        });
    })
}
```

The array mapping:

```
{
    recursos.length > 0
        ? recursos.map((item, key) => {
            return (
                <tr key={key}>
                    <td><CheckBox title={item.nome} checked={Conexoes.Bool(item.ativo)}></CheckBox></td>
                    <td>
                        <Button title="Editar" onClick={e => {
                            setValorEditar(item.nome);
                            setAtivo(item.ativo);
                            setIdEditar(item.id);
                            setMenuEditar(true);
                            setTitleEditar("Editar Recurso");
                        }}
                        >
                        </Button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            );
        })

        : <></>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, any of the code you write should be in English.

In terms of the updating of the array, please try to:

```
setRecursos([...recursos, retorno.Values])
```

as you might be overwriting the previous values and only store the values from the latest response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait till your promise is resolved

```
const getRecursos = async () => {
    Conexoes.Consultar(ma, password, "recurso").then(retorno => {
        console.log(retorno.Valores);
        setRecursos(retorno.Valores);
    })
        .catch(erro => {
            console.log(erro);
            alert("Erro Catch")
        }
        )
}

// use the async function like this
const recursos = await getRecursos();
```

Same story for `salvarEdicao`, `Atualizar`...
Please check more about [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)